# Replace String variable with exact string

Tags: java, replace

If i want to replace one string variable with exact string in java, what can I do?

I know that replace in java , replace one exact string with another, but now i have string variable and i want to replace it's content with another exact string.

for example:

```
`String str="abcd";
String rep="cd";`
```

Now I want to replace rep content with`"kj"`
It means that I want to have `str="abkj"` at last.

Comment: `want to replace it's content with another exact string.`. makes no sense to me.

Comment: Please clarify, or give an example

Comment: I edit my question and add example to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you could use [`String.replace(CharSequence, CharSequence)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) like

```
String str="abcd";
String rep="cd";
String nv = "kj";
str = str.replace(rep, nv); // <-- old, new
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is (the requested)

```
abkj
```

Comment: I do exact thing as you, but it doesn't work. let me see my code again. thank you

Answer (score 0):

i think he wants:

```
String toReplace = "REPLACE_ME";
"REPLACE_ME What a nice day!".replace(toReplace,"");
```

"REPLACEME What a nice day!".replace(toReplace,"") results in:

```
" What a nice day!"
```